# Passport application says unmarried though marital status is married

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

My friend who is married, applied for passport last year and selected unmarried as her marital status. She did that as she didn't want to change her last name and in India people say you have to change your last name after marriage (which I know is not compulsory by law). When interviewer asked her "are you married?" she said no as she got scared because the application says unmarried. Now she wants to correct it but her police verification is in order. I suggested to do it now and do not continue with the mistake.

But the problem is you need a reason for cancellation and she is again scared that they would ask why did you lie to interviewer?

And this might delay her application process.

What do you think should be done in order to get it corrected?

Comment: What interview are you talking about?

Comment: Does your friend have a marriage certificate? And has she already received her passport?

Comment: That is a very flimsy reason to say unmarried when you are married.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment the risk is having to pay a [fine](https://advocatedelhi.wordpress.com/penalty-for-offences-under-passport-act-1967/) that might be INR 500:

> Minor suppressions of information regarding marital status / name of spouse etc. inadvertently.

*Assuming* she can get away with "inadvertently" †.

Leave this to fester and not only might the fine increase merely through the passage of time but it might switch to a higher basis (currently INR 2,500):

> In case applicant does not disclose correct marital status and a case is registered regarding marital dispute

In addition, the consequences may become much more serious. For example, if seeking to join her husband should he obtain work abroad, wherever that may be, passport details that do not a match marriage certificate will certainly complicate any visa/residency application and may even mean a visa or residency is not granted.

The damage has been done and she can expect to pay the price for her stupidity at some point. But the longer she puts off doing so the greater the possible adverse consequences.

† If not (and the chances of getting away with "inadvertently" will probably reduce as time goes on):

> whoever contravenes the provisions of the Act by traveling without a
>   valid passport, knowingly furnishes wrong information or attempts to
>   alter entries made on the passports or travel documents, fails to
>   produce his/her passport for inspection, knowing uses a passport or
>   travel document issued to another person or knowingly allows another
>   person to use a passport or travel document issued to him shall be
>   punishable with imprisonment for a term up to 2 years or  with fine up
>   to Rs. 5,000/- or with both

So to get it corrected "own up" and go back to where the passport application was made, as you suggest.